# When I try to Login as a Teacher I get the error : EndOfStreamException Unhandled

Tags: vb.net

Here is the code for the Teacher Login, where once run and a valid account is tried to login to the system then the error : EndOfStreamException Unhandled

Any help would be appreciated to fix this

```
Private Sub BtnTLogin_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)    Handles BtnTLogin.Click
    If TxtUsername.Text = "" Or TxtPassword.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please enter all the Login details for the account")
    End If'

    Filenamet = "TeacherAccounts.txt"

    FileOpenStatusT = False
    Dim Filefound As Boolean
    Filefound = False
    FileOpen(1, Filenamet, OpenMode.Input)
    While Filefound = False
        Input(1, Username)
        Input(1, Password)
        Input(1, namet)
        Input(1, surnamet)

        If Username = TxtUsername.Text And Password = TxtPassword.Text Then
            Filefound = True
        End If
    End While
    If Filefound = False Then
        MsgBox("Username and Password were not a match,please try again")
    Else
        TeacherMenu.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End If

    FileClose(1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this an upgraded VB6 application? It's using a lot of older functionality. Broadly, `EndOfStreamException` suggests that you tried to read past the end of the file. The way this routine is coded, it looks like this will happen anytime the given username and password are not present in the file.

Comment: I don't think its a upgraded application, I don't know quite what you mean by that. The student login works fine and is the exact code just changed to suit the Teacher variables. The text file contains the Username and Password being entered so are present within the file.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few potential problems with the code. The ones I see that *might* be related to your problem are:

```
If TxtUsername.Text = "" Or TxtPassword.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox("Please enter all the Login details for the account")
End If'
```

If either TextBox is empty, this will display the message box, but will then continue to try to lookup the empty username or password in the file.

```
Dim Filefound As Boolean
Filefound = False
FileOpen(1, Filenamet, OpenMode.Input)
While Filefound = False
    Input(1, Username)
    Input(1, Password)
    Input(1, namet)
    Input(1, surnamet)

    If Username = TxtUsername.Text And Password = TxtPassword.Text Then
        Filefound = True
    End If
End While
If Filefound = False Then
    ...
```

`Filefound` will never be `False` at the end of the while-loop. Either a match will be found, so `Filefound` is `True`, or no match will be found. Since there is no end-of-file checking, this will likely result in the `EndOfStream` exception you are seeing. Since you're using the older FileSystem methods, you can use EOF(1) to check whether you're at the end of the file.

Your best bet might be to step through the loop, checking the `Username` and `Password` variables each iteration to see if you're reading what you expect to be reading.